# GLTF model animation lagging out my entire computer

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, gltf, codesandbox

I'm fairly new to the web design world, currently designing with models and displacement maps using threejs.

I've successfully imported a GLTF model with animations "working". However, every time I uncomment my update function inside my animation function, the animation of the model makes my whole computer lag.
How would I be able to animate my model without this lag? I would want the model's animations to run smoothly but this lag seems unnecessary for such a low poly model.

Let me know if you need to see any other lines of code.
Thanks!

I've tried to increase the number of which my update function divides by to 500. This seems to be the only way to make the animation 'smooth'. However, this lags out my PC beyond usability.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilpxl.png)

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Also, if possible, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) replicating the issue - you can do that on sites such as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), [codepen](https://codepen.io), etc.

Comment: combine your update and animate function into one so you only call requestAnimationFrame on one function and only call renderer.render once per frame. How you have it now, you are rendering the scene twice per frame. Other than that, there is nothing wrong with the very small amount of code you have posted.